# How was the "vibrating string" studied?

Tags: history, vibrations, string, harmonics

[The vibrating string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_string) is used to derive a lot of theory regarding strings, such as the theory about harmonics.

However, since the string movement and specifically the phenomenon of harmonics seems difficult to observe (the string moves too fast),

how was the discovery of e.g. harmonics possible?
How is the string observed or measured in order to draw such conclusions?

Comment: Did you read the last section of the Wikipedia article that you are citing? It says that these strings can be conveniently studied with stroboscopes. Having said that, they don't cause a whole lot of theoretical problems, indeed there are few systems as easily understood as the one-dimensional vibrating string, so I am not sure that there has been that much experimental effort expended on them except in professions that make a living with them, e.g. by makers of string instruments.

Comment: @CuriousOne Yeah there's that paragraph, but I didn't find it too englightnening. Specifically because the mathematical statement of the theory of harmonics is exact. I don't understand how the measurements have been carried in order to display close correspondence to the mathematical accuracy.

Comment: I am not aware that one can do any precision tests on vibrating strings, there are too many first order effects that depend on material properties and the damping of strings is very high compared to other shapes of vibrating mechanical resonators. That pretty much makes the system of little interest to physicists, I am afraid. Today you can use fairly cheap electronics to get an almost perfect measurement on these things, if you like, but it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @CuriousOne Then there's also the thing that in digital signal processing one can display that the phenomenon in some sense holds. Because one can simulate harmonics. This is how e.g. string sound synthesis is possible.

Comment: If you are interested in musical synthesis, then you are simply in the wrong department, I am afraid. Physics doesn't care about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33435/discussion-between-curiousone-and-mavavilj).